# ExtJS 4 callParent not working

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to figure out why callParent isn't working.

Here's some code:

```
Ext.define('AM.ArView', {
extend:'Ext.window.Window',
initComponent: function() {
    var foo = this;
    console.log(foo);

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://my/awesome/path',
        success: function(response, opts) {
            console.log(foo);
            foo.callParent();
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}
});
```

Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'superclass' of undefined

I need to load the windows items via ajax

Comment: anyhow, a solution is making a synchronous call.

Comment: Intercepting the initComponent such way is.. very strange. I'd recommend to use a special event for this.

Comment: it is not strange at all, and async call is possible and very reasonable, see my answer below please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei Julian!

I needed to do a similar operation, and i ended up wrappign the ajax request in a function which i pass a callback function into it to execute when the request is done, and from the call back i launch the windows.

In terms of code, it would be something like:

```
//Request function
 LoadThoseDamnWindows: function (callback)
    {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'checklist/GetList',
            success: function(response, opts) {
                console.log(response);
                callback.call(this, response);
            },
            failure: function(response, opts) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }
```

then you call int lets, say ona  button click:

```
        {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Help',
                iconCls: 'help',
                    scope: this,
                handler: function(){
                    //Call function
                    this.LoadThoseDamnWindows(function(loadedData){

                        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
                            autoShow: true,
                            layout: 'fit',
                            title: "My Cool window",
                            html: "My window content with dynamic loaded data" + loadedData.responseText
                        });

                    });
                }
            }
```

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to pass callback with `callParent` into `Ext.Msg.*` dialog. Honestly I didn't understand how to use code from answer for my case... and solved it with hack.

Working in 4.0.7:

```
methodName: function () {
    var me = this,
        args = arguments;
    // do some stuff
    function customCallback() {
        // do some stuff inside callback
        // hacks for calling parent method from callback
        var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
        caller.$owner = me;
        caller.$name = 'methodName';
        me.callParent(args);
    }
    // do more stuff, pass callback anywhere
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but hope it helps others...

Instead of calling `this.callParent();`

You need to call `this.self.superclass.foo.call(this);`

foo being the superclass method you want to call.

To wrap it up and make it look more meanful:

```
callParentManually: function (myscope, methodname) {
    myscope.self.superclass[methodname].call(myscope);
}

//and then ...
callParentManually(me, 'initComponent');
```

See this:

[ExtJS 4 - async callback to callParent throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383894/extjs-4-async-callback-to-callparent-throws-exception)