# ExtJS 4 - async callback to callParent throws exception

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to prepare some Json Store before processing to `callParent()`, then it throws an error.

However, `me.callParent()` works fine outside without async callback.

```
Ext.define('My.desktop.AppExt', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.App',

    someStore: null,

    init: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.someStore = Ext.create('My.store.SomeStore');
        me.someStore.load({
            scope: this,
            url: 'some/json/url',
            callback: function(records, opt, success) {
                 if (success) {
                     me.callParent(); // BOOM! ERROR HERE
                 }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

ERROR:

Unhandled exception at line 4245, column 17 in //localhost/js/ext-all-debug.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error:

**Unable to get property 'superclass' of undefined or null reference**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

callParent relies on the context to call the right method, so if you're not actually calling it "directly" from a subclass method, you'll need to invoke it manually:

```
Ext.define('A', {
    foo: function(){
        console.log('foo', 'a');    
    }
});

Ext.define('B', {
    extend: 'A',
    bar: function(){
        this.self.superclass.foo.call(this);    
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    var o = new B();
    o.bar();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I wonder with the async calls, apart from callParent() is there any other functions that are similar in the same situation that I should be aware of?

Comment: `callParent` interrogates the calling function to figure out what needs to be called. So, anything that looks like a "magic" call uses the same technique.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this purpose is to get link to parentMethod like at callParent() function, but without invoking it:

```
/**
 * Returns reference to the parent class method. Works as {@link Ext.Base#callParent}, but doesn't invoke the
 * method.
 * @return {Function} Parent class method.
 */
getParentMethod: function() {
    var method,
        superMethod = (method = this.getParentMethod.caller) && (method.$previous ||
            ((method = method.$owner ? method : method.caller) && method.$owner.superclass[method.$name]));
    return superMethod;
},  


sampleMethod: function() {
    var parentMethod = this.getParentMethod();
    var parentArguments = arguments;
    someAsyncFunc(function() {
        parentMethod.apply(this, parentArguments); // calls parent.sampleMethod(...)
    }, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I know is to use extra parameter, that indicates that parent method should be called:

```
init: function(callParent) {
    if (callParent) {
        this.callParent();
    }
    var me = this;
    me.someStore = Ext.create('My.store.SomeStore');
    me.someStore.load({
        scope: this,
        url: 'some/json/url',
        callback: function(records, opt, success) {
             if (success) {
                 this.init(true);
             }
        }
    });
}
```

If you use this.self.superclass.init.call(this) it will be ok only until somebody will create child for your class. this.self.superclass points to superclass of **instance**'s class, so it would points to My.desktop.AppExt instead of Ext.ux.desktop.App.

**Updated 24.08.2016: Published smarter solution (see another answer by me).**